# Having trouble with viewing a layout in AIDE

Tags: android, image, layout, preview, aide

I'm making an app in AIDE (It's like an android studio but for Android) and I'm struggling to add images to it. Every time I add an image (an src for the image to be exact), I don't have any preview and it tells me this:

"Can not view the layout. Attempt to invoke interface 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"

I searched for a while but if I'm doing something wrong but even though I copied the exact code, there is still no luck in the preview but there is no error in the code at all. It still runs and I can see the image when I open the app itself.

This is the code in my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#9F0900"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I don't know if this can help but I'll also show you the java file for the xml

```
package com.luminetech.metaspecs;

import android.content.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        
        Thread th = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent in = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                }
                catch (Exception e){}
            }
        };
        th.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to roll back your android device to android version 10 and no higher.  Since android studio for android devices does not support viewing on later versions of android.

Answer (score 0):

Omit all @ references i e @string/hello_world
Instead use "Hello World!"
directly the value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).